# What's the equivalent of Clojure's "do" in Common Lisp?

Tags: clojure, common-lisp

That is, a form that evaluates child forms in order and returns the last evaluated value,e.g.

```
(do (println "Hello World") 3) => 3
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It's called [`progn`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_progn.htm).

> ### *Special Operator* [PROGN](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_progn.htm)
>
> #### Syntax:
>
> **progn** *form** ⇒ *result**
>
> #### Description:
>
> **progn** evaluates *forms*, in the order in which they are given.
>
> The values of each *form* but the last are discarded.

Comment: About the name: It's called `progn` because it returns the value of the `n`th form. There's also `prog1` that returns the value of the first form. (And even `prog2` that returns the value of the second form, though it's hardly ever used!)